# Calculate EOS account resources CPU, RAM and NET in percentage

Tags: accounts, ram, cpu, resources, net

I am designing my own EOS dashboard in which I want to show the respective account's resources `CPU, NET and RAM` in Percentage as they are in the attached picture (from https://local.bloks.io/):

[image]

when I get account information, I am getting values `max cpu_limit, used cpu_limit, available cpu_limit, max net_limit, used net_limit, available net_limit, ram_quota and ram_usage`. I tried to calculate percentage same for all using:

```
var cpuProgress = ((double)cpuUsed / cpuMax) * 100.0;
var cpuPercentage = cpuProgress.ToString("#0.##%", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But I guess I am mistaken. Please help how to calculate these three resources in percentage?

Answer (score 1):

The values you are using should be correct for CPU and NET. `max` for the max the user has and `used` for what they currently have consumed. There should also be `available` which is how much they have remaining. used + available = max.

For RAM however it would be `ram_quota` and `ram_usage`.

So I would use something like this, changing the variable names to whatever you are using.

```
parseFloat((cpu_limit.used / cpu_limit.max) * 100);
```

Be sure that however you are assigning these variables when you retrieve the account information that the correct values are being stored.

Comment: The values type is `long`. Cannot use `parseFloat`.

Comment: It's parsing the result of the division, not the values, example:  
(56383/3408838) * 100 = 1.65402403986  
You can then add `.toFixed(2)` on the end to force it to two decimal places.  
I am using this very method in a React app.